# Is it possible to navigate the user through an app to mobile's wifi settings and connect with a wifi network with predefined password in ios?

Tags: ios, swift

In my application I am going to navigate the user from my app to mobile's wifi settings to connect with one of the available wifi networks 
I know very well that we cannot search and connect with a wifi network through an application in iOS so to connect manually I have some questions about that

1.Can we show particular(filter) name of wifi networks in wifi settings page while navigating, if yes how can we do it?

2.can we pass any value to settings page from my app because all SSID and passwords can get from server itself. If I pass the password to wifi settings page it might be easy to prevent the user to type password while connecting

3.If we cannot pass any value to wifi setting page then is there any other way to connect the user without entering the password because we should not show the password to the user

The above questions are just my ideas but don't know whether I am asking in correct way or not. I am new to this development. Can any one help me please? Thanks in advance

Comment: No no no and no. You are sandboxed.

Answer (score 2):

As @matt already wrote it isn't possible from inside an app sandbox.

Apple only provides the company solution [Mobile Device Management (MDM)](https://www.apple.com/support/business/mdm/) for device administration. My last customer used it to configure the wifi for all company devices, so user do not have to enter any credentials.

But it's the users choice at last which wifi he/she wants to connect with.